Windows 11, Nvidia 3080, HDMI video out works, but windows detects no HDMI audio device
My system:

Windows 11 23H2
Nvidia 3080 FE
Denon AVR-S960H receiver connected to HDMI output from vid card

I used all of this hardware before with Win 10 for years with no issues. I installed Win 11 a few weeks ago, and for a while it was working fine. But then the HDMI audio started getting flaky. Now, I cannot even get the receiver to show up in the list of Windows audio devices. Nvidia is aware of the device:

Windows is aware of the device too:

And Windows still puts out video to the device. But no longer audio:

I've done many searches and tried many things. Reinstalled video drivers. Updated video drivers, straight from Nvidia. Disabled every bit of onboard video/audio I can find (USB audio, Realtek, etc) directly in BIOS (in an attempt to resolve potential conflict with Nvidia HDMI output). Restarted Windows services related to audio. Deleting/reinstalling any video/audio related hardware in device manager. I am fully stumped. Bluetooth audio devices still work fine.
Any ideas? More data from device manager (hidden entries shown) if it helps:

